# literature related to Spectral resolution

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection, resolution

I  am interested in spectral resolution of spectral estimation methods.

Can you point me to some good literature, videos or books from which i can read and study?

I want to understand how to resolve  two closed spaced sinusoids:
$$
x_1(t) = \sin(\omega_1 t + \phi_1) \\
x_2(t) = \sin(\omega_2 t + \phi_2) \\
$$
where $\omega_1 \approx \omega_2$.

Comment: Your question is very vague, and cannot be easily answered. Please define what you mean by resolution capacity and what specifically you need to know.

Comment: i want  methods and generally theoretical approaches for spectral resolution,by spectral resolution i mean when we have  closed spaced deterministic components according to  their frequency and amplitudes,what methods exist  for  their differentiation or  how to distinguish from each other this components

Comment: Please update your question, then you will be able to select it for re-opening. "Resolution capacity" didn't make much sense to me. "Spectral resolution" makes much more sense.

Comment: i have changed ,could you see please

Comment: yes even instead of  two sinusoid,it could be a lot of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend
Array Signal Processing - Johnson, Dudgeon. This book covers classical spectral estimation, Minimum Variance Distortionless Response (MVDR), Linear Prediction, and subspace methods (e.g. MUSIC and ESPIRIT). It provides examples of the resolution capabilities between these methods. The are quite a number of good references in this book if you require additional detail.

MUSIC and ESPIRIT type algorithms are dicussed in most advanced DSP texts:
Advanced Digital Signal Processing, Proakis, Rader, Ling, Nikias
Discrete Random Signals and Statistical Signal Processing, Therrien

For parametric methods:
Spectral Analysis - A modern Perspective (Kay, Marple) Proc. IEEE Vol 6, No 11, 1981
Modern Spectral Estimation: Theory and Application, Steven Kay
Digital Spectral Analysis - S.L. Marple
SPECTRAL ANALYSIS OF SIGNALS - P Stoica and R Moses  PDF is available [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~ps/ref.html)

The books by Marple and Kay tend to focus on algorithms i.e. implementations of various MA, AR, and ARMA approaches (e.g. fast Lattice filter implementations) rather than the performance of a basic approach

Compressive Sensing / Sparse Reconstruction techniques can also be used. There are too many references here to list. There are a few books by these authors Michael Elad, Yonina Eldar, and Holger Rauhut. These techniques are often quoted as "having super resolution properties"

The algorithms are often hard to compare directly because they all have twiddle factors which affect their performance.  For example
 1. For MA, AR, ARMA, what order of model to use?
 2. For Compressive techniques - how closely to space the template vectors? What level of regularization to use? How many frequencies are there? How many samples do we have?

Comment: but also AR,MA,ARMA model is used only for stationary model right?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking into the MUSIC and ESPIRIT algorithms for constrained parameter estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the "Chirp z transform" (somtimes referred to as the zoom FFT").  You can go to a good standard DSP reference. I believe you can find this as public domain on the internet. The book is:

"Digital Signal Processing" by Oppenheim and Schafer
See chapter 6, section 6.

This techniques allows you to concentrate you're calculations on a narrow range of frequencies. You would "zoom" into the range of your two closely spaced sine waves.

You can also google "chirp z transform", "zoom z transform" or "zoom FFT".

Comment: is this book free on internet?if you can give me links please

Comment: i have one question if i have  signal,what i should   know in advance  so that usage of  Chirp z transform was effective?

Comment: Just for the record: the Chirp Z-transform and the zoom FFT are not the same thing!

Comment: I've seen the two terms used interchangeably, though this may be poor usage.  Can you direct me to a technical presentation of the zoom z transform.  The discussion in  the reference I provided is on the chirp z transform.

Comment: http://www-elec.inaoep.mx/~rogerio/discrete-time%20digital%20signal%20processing%20-%20oppenheim,%20schafer%20&%20buck.pdf See chaper 9.  This is the same author and contains much of the same material.

Comment: To use the chirp z transform, you have to know the region of the frequency spectrum that you want to "zoom" into.  If you are looking for arbitrary frequencies, this technique won't be useful, unless you develop a way to move the analysis region dynamically.

Comment: @BZ Briefly, the Zoom-FFT can be a simple complex band shift to baseband, followed by regular FFT'ing. However you are right, they are used interchangeably in colloquial speak.

Comment: Zoom FFT is a frequency shift via complex modulation followed by low-pass filtering, decimation, and then an FFT. Here's a [link](http://www.embedded.com/design/other/4213370/Using-Zoom-FFT-for-spectral-analysis) to an article by Rick Lyons.